# Git SSH RSA keys

Tags: git

I thought I set up my key pairs correctly -- I can do git pulls.  I can do git commits.  But when I do a git push, it counts objects, decompresses, then says: fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly.

What's the issue here?

I'm a super user, so it's not folder writable / readable access problems -- it must be the way I set up the encryption key pair... how do I debug this ... since git pull works?

Comment: What's the -1 for ?

Comment: Are you using git:// or ssh://?

Comment: ssh://  ..............

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you **sure** you have write access to the GIT repository?

1. If you are you using the git://
   protocol: You can't push over git://
   without special settings. Write access defaults to disabled, as far as I know.
2. If you are
   using the ssh:// protocol: Log in
   normally and check if you have write
   access to the git repository.
   Navigate to it and try to touch a
   new file. Then remove the new file.

Comment: can't write to the git repository ... even as a super user, unless i invoke sudo

Comment: So there is your problem. Make sure you have write access as the user. Typically you do this by creating/using a group (users, gitusers or similar) and then assigning that group to the repository. Give the group write access. You might have to fiddle a bit to ensure that new files are created with correct GID.

Comment: thanks a  lot: another quick question: my ubuntu came with a www directory which contains all of our web content ... with root as owner and root as group.  should i change this to a different owner / group?

Comment: nevermind ... got it!

Comment: I would upvote you; but I don't have rep :)

Comment: If you have a stackoverflow account you can always link them for 100 rep ;)